# How the logging module in Python manages saving files

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the Python `logging` module to log what's going on in my application on both on a file and into the terminal.

My code is:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, handlers=[  # stream=sys.stdout,
                            logging.FileHandler("debug.log", 'a'),
                            logging.StreamHandler()
                        ], format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', )

logging.info("This is a LOG INFO message")
```

Now, as soon as the program runs, it saves the log on a file.

I would like to know how the `logging` method save this info on the file. Does it *opens -> write -> close* the file evry time a `logging` line is called? Do keep the file open until the program ends?

I'm asking because if my software crash for some reasons or the PC reboot, the already written log file is safe or it could be corrupted?

Comment: I would very much assume logging is built to not corrupt the log in case of a crash, otherwise it'd be quite useless.

Comment: @Peter yeah, that should be the login answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the names suggests the handlers you have set here, *stream* their log messages to the specified sinks. [Logging Handler Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) states that it:

> "[...] sends logging output to streams such as sys.stdout, sys.stderr or any file-like object (or, more precisely, any object which supports write() and flush() methods)."

Looking at the [Source Code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc5d37671d2b9f31850a9edaa495fadae038759/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1082) and considering this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/headsrooms/0e8d8c68c9d5eb9723da998760b9872c) since you apparently could use a logging instance with a context manager if you really wanted to, I would make the assumption that your intuition was exactly correct (regarding open > write > close).

Comment: The important takeaway more generally from this answer is that if you're curious about the functionality of a particular module, it's generally trivial to locate the source code driving the specific behavior you're curious about.